# java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get list of LatLng from Firebase database. Previously, I've insert Polygon list by this code,  `mMarkerPoints.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));` and by this `databaseReference.child("Area").child(pushId).child("region").setValue(mMarkerPoints);` the databse sturcture as,

[image]

Now, I want to get this mMarkerPoints from database. for this, I wrote code,    `List<LatLng> areaRegion = (ArrayList) dataSnapshot.child(key).child("region").getValue();`, this code give me exception. How to get this list?

code:

```
databaseReference.child("Area").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                                            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                                                String key = dataSnapshot1.child(dataSnapshot1.getKey()).getKey();
                                                                String areaName = dataSnapshot.child(key).child("name").getValue(String.class);
                                                                List<LatLng> areaRegion = (ArrayList<LatLng>) dataSnapshot.child(key).child("region").getValue();

                                                                for(int i = 0; i<values.size();i++) {
                                                                       Log.d("sdfljdjw", values.get(i));
                                                                  }
```

Little bit solution:
i got this result `{longitude=71.43064320087433, latitude=32.392359285468686}` by this code:

```
Object value = dataSnapshot.child(key).child("region").getValue();
                                                                if(value instanceof List) {
                                                                    List<Object> sdfsd = (List<Object>) value;

                                                                    for(int i = 0; i<sdfsd.size();i++) {
                                                                        Log.d("sdfljdjw", sdfsd.get(i)+"");
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                                else {
                                                                    Log.d("sdfljdjw", "no");
                                                                }
```

now how to convert this values to LatLng object?

> 10-10 14:20:30.539
>   11935-11935/com.example.salesman.salesmantrackingsystem
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
>           at com.example.salesman.salesmantrackingsystem.LoginActivity$1$1$1$1.onDataChange(LoginActivity.java:154)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)

Comment: post your code and exception logs

Comment: check it please

Comment: post that part of code also

Comment: if you closely see the structure, it is not an arraylist that you are trying to fetch but is a hashmap as the error says. So try to fetch values in form of hashmap instead of arraylist

Comment: @VivekMishra please tell how to do that?

Comment: you get that in hashmap and then convert it into list

Comment: @UdayRamjiyani i wrote this but again got error.  Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.child(key).child("region").getValue();

Comment: Can you please provide the structure for your entire database tree so I can provide you an answer? And please responde with @AlexMamo.

Comment: @AlexMamo in the picture attached, the region node have list. i want to get this list.

Comment: @zohaib The picture is incomplete, that's I was asking you to add a more complete one. Can you add it?

Comment: @AlexMamo the region child have 46 elements. its imposible to capture their screenshot

Comment: @zohaib I don't want all children. I want to see only the upper ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess (untested), replace:

```
List<LatLng> areaRegion = (ArrayList<LatLng>) dataSnapshot.child(key).child("region").getValue();
```

with something like:

```
List<LatLng> areaRegion = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> locations = (List<Object>) dataSnapshot.child(key).child("region").getValue();
for (Object locationObj : locations) {
  Map<String, Object> location = (Map<String, Object>) locationObj;
  LatLng latLng = new LatLng((Double) location.get("latitude")), (Double) location.get("longitude"));
  areaRegion.add(latLng);
}
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Comment: error in this line Map<String, Object> locations = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.child(key).child("region").getValue();

Comment: @zohaib: Updated to cast to a list instead.

Comment: No problems, it was a process of trial and error. If you need more information on pulling out data from a `DataSnapshot`, take a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
  Map<String, Object> td = (HashMap<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

    List<Object> values = td.values();
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$Values cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: this should work, may be you are missing something, just try to debug and see the hasmap values you are getting in the first line which is map. if it is not giving exception there and if those are the correct values which you want to access, after that map that map to list object

Comment: Might be better to just cast to `Map<String, Object>` instead of guessing a concrete type.

Comment: first just see that r u getting the values in map or not, that should happen and if that is not happening than you say that you are not able to acces values in map or whatever is the case, instead of just not working. that will help solve your problem, always give more information.

Comment: by this code i got value like. {longitude=71.43064320087433, latitude=32.392359285468686} code:  Object value = dataSnapshot.child(key).child("region").getValue();
if(value instanceof List) {
List<Object> sdfsd = (List<Object>) value; for(int i = 0; i<sdfsd.size();i++) {
                                                                        Log.d("sdfljdjw", sdfsd.get(i)+"");
                                                                    }
                                                                }

Comment: but i dont know how to convert this array to LatLng type

Answer (score 0):

2 examples:

first example read one object (defined key "clave2") from hashmap( String,Alumno) and second example read all objects from hashmap(String,Alumno) (valid for HashMap/List)

```
    DatabaseReference myRefalumnos1 = database.getReference("alumnoshashmap");
    myRefalumnos1.child("clave2").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            Alumno value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Alumno.class);
            System.out.println(value.toString());
            Log.i( "firebase1", value.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.i( "firebase1", String.valueOf(error.toException()));
        }
    });
   


    DatabaseReference myRefalumnos2 = database.getReference("alumnoshashmap");
    myRefalumnos2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<Alumno> alumnos = new ArrayList<Alumno>();
            for (DataSnapshot keynode : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                keys.add(keynode.getKey());
                alumnos.add(keynode.getValue(Alumno.class));
            }
            for (String k : keys) {
                System.out.println(k);
                Log.i("firebase1", "clave leida " + k);
            }
            for (Alumno a : alumnos) {
                System.out.println(a.toString());
                Log.i("firebase1", "alumno leido " + a.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.i( "firebase1", String.valueOf(error.toException()));
        }
    });
```